# Test if the windows location is correctly set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am setting windows location in my `useEffect` hook as follows.

```
const MyComponent = (name) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.location.href = `/${name}/mypath${window.location.search}`
  }, []);

  return <Fragment/>;
};
```

I am looking to test that the `href` value matches correctly.

Thus I am mocking the data as follows and expecting the value to match following String.

```
www.test.com/name/mypath?param=1
```

But I end up with error saying that the window.location.href's value is actually the following.

```
/[object Object]/mypath?param=1
```

It is missing the host and also not capturing the name prop's value in the href. Could I get some advice on what I doing wrong? Thanks.

My test as follows.

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(f => f());

delete window.location;
window = Object.create(window);
const host = "www.test.com";
const search = '?param=1'
Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
  value: {
    host,
    search
  },
  writable: true
});

describe('My tests', () => {
  const render = () => shallow(
    <MyComponent name='name' />
  );

  it('should pass', () => {
    const rendered = render();
    const url = 'www.test.com/name/mypath?param=1';
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual(url);
  });
});
```

Comment: The test is correct, the _implementation_ is wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could I pls check why the implementation is wrong?

Comment: Well the test output tells you name is an object; maybe think about why that could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to destructure the props argument for your component,

It should be

```js
const MyComponent = ({name}) => {
//rest of your code

}
```

The reason is component functions receive only one argument, which is an object with all the props you passed. What you did is just called it `name`. What I did is destructure the `name` property from the props object, i.e. took the value that was passed in the `name` prop